# Watchkit app control volume parent iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I have a question, Is it possible to control volume from Apple Watch of iOS App? I mean, for example if I have an WKSlider to control volume on the iOS app with objective c, is that possible and what control do I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After double-checking the docs to be sure, there's no API in WatchKit to do what you describe. The Watch OS includes the ability to control volume itself in the "Now Playing" glance, so allowing apps to do it would be redundant.